# MEF: Despite having found and loaded the PRISM modules, app claims they can't be found

Tags: c#, .net, prism, mef

I am utilizing MEF in my PRISM 4.0 application to load the modules.
In order to be sure that they are being downloaded I have made my Shell to import IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification.  Then within the OnImportSatirsfied() method, I can clearly see in the debugger that the two modules are found. (See screenshot below)

[image]

However I keep getting this error message:

> Unable to locate the module with type
>   'SalesContactManagement.Modules.NavigationModule.NavigationModule,
>   SalesContactManagement.Modules.NavigationModule, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicToken=null' among the exported modules. Make
>   sure the module name in the module catalog matches that specified on
>   ModuleExportAttribute for the module type.

Any idea why MEF doesn't work?  Any help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Funny enough when I empty the NavigationModule to a minimum it works fine.

```
 [ModuleExport(typeof(NavigationModule))]
    public class NavigationModule : IModule
    {
        private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
        private readonly ToolbarViewModel _toolbarViewModel;

        public void Initialize()
        {

        }

        //[ImportingConstructor]
        //public NavigationModule(RegionManager regionManager)
        //{
        //    //_toolbarViewModel = toolbarViewModel;
        //    _regionManager = regionManager;
        //}
}
```

But as soon as I put an ImportingContructor there, for types that are already registered in Bootstrapper, it fails. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done anything with Prism, but is the `IRegionManager` type exported? Your importing constructor is currently:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public NavigationModule(RegionManager regionManager) { }
```

Whereas, should it be:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public NavigationModule(IRegionManager regionManager) { }
```

Notice the difference between the class `RegionManager` and the interface `IRegionManager` as the constructor argument.

**Edit**: For your comment. If you want to spin up a new instance each time, you could use either the `PartCreationPolicyAttribute`:

```
[Export(typeof(ISomething)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
```

Or, you could use `ExportFactory`, e.g.:

```
[Import] ExportFactory<ISomething> SomethingFactory { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I have finally solved it. Debugging MEF is so much harder than Unity. But its interesting. It was one of the imports down the line that got rejected, hence it rejected the whole chain incl the Module. It made me believe the module wasn't found instead. I like MEF. Let see. I have one more question, do you know how I force MEF to get a new instance? I keep getting the same instance, even if its defined as non-shared...maybe I should make this a new question though...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [fusion log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28VS.71%29.aspx) to find how the modules are loaded. Fusion log viewer should be installed for you when you install Visual Studio (you should be able to just hit start + fusion to search for it)

Possible issues:

1. Version mismatch
2. Strong name mismatch
3. LoadContext mismatch
4. Something else

Fusion Log Viewer might be able to help you pinpoint the error.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have started it but the first three buttons are greyed out. Do I have to drag and drop a log file on it ?

Comment: You have to run it as administrator. Also note that you have to turn it the settings after use as othewise the fusion loader will continue to log (hurts performance and takes diskspace)